# Wait until all images are loaded in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, load

How can I wait until all images are loaded in React.JS?

The problem is that I do some calculations (image processing) using those images and the results are different between multiple refreshes of the browser because at certain times the calculations start before the images are 100% loaded. Is there a way to wait until 100% of all images are loaded?

I've tried something like this:

```
const [imagesLoaded, setImagesLoaded] = useState(false);
```

```
{images.map((image, index) => {
   return <ShowImage source={image} index={index+1} key={index} onLoad={() => setImagesLoaded(index)} />
})}
```

```
const ShowImage: React.FC<{source:string, index: number, onLoad: () => void}> = ({source, index, onLoad}) => {
    return (
        <img src={source} width="640" height="480" id={'image' + index} alt={'image' + index} onLoad={onLoad}/>
    )
}
```

And the 'checker':

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(imagesLoaded === 5) {
      ... do something
   }
}, [imagesLoaded]);
```

But the problem is that this is working only for the first page render, if I refresh is not working, but I refresh one more time is working again and sometimes needs more refreshes, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your `ShowImage` component to only set `imagesLoaded` when the last image source URL is loaded.

```
function ShowImages({ urls, setImagesLoaded }) {
  const onLoad = (index) => {
    if (index === urls.length - 1) {
      setImagesLoaded(true)
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {urls.map((url, index) => (
        <img src={url} onLoad={() => onLoad(index)} key={url} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default ShowImages;
```

And use the component something like this

```
const [imagesLoaded, setImagesLoaded] = useState(false);
...

useEffect(() => {
   if(imagesLoaded) {
      ... do something
   }
}, [imagesLoaded]);

...
<ShowImages urls={images} setImagesLoaded={setImagesLoaded}/>
```

[Working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wait-for-image-load-f0t8wh)

Comment: That's odd. There must be some other code causing additional renders.  Here's a working example and as you can see it only runs the useEffect after all images have been loaded. https://codesandbox.io/s/wait-for-image-load-f0t8wh

Answer (score 0):

Your images might not load in the intended order. If your 4th image loads after the 5th one, then the value of `imagesLoaded` will be `4` at the end.
To prevent that, I would increment the value one at a time, so when all five images are loaded the value will be 5.

```js
onLoad={() => setImagesLoaded(v => v + 1)}
```